# Is there a benefit to using <=> rather than just sorting and reversing?

Tags: ruby

What are the benefits (if any) of doing:

`books.sort! { |firstBook, secondBook| secondBook <=> firstBook }`

versus:

`books.sort!.reverse!`

The second option just seems so much cleaner and easier to understand..

**edit:** I guess this might be a question of, what are other uses of the <=> operator other than 1-to-1 sorting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My initial answer about performance concerns has proven to be largely based on an incorrect assumption: There is no performance impact inherent in `sort.reverse`, as `sort` with no block appears to be faster than `sort` *with* a block, so much so that it offsets the cost of a second `reverse` call, which is negligible.

However, the gist of my answer remains valid: You should choose the second line because it is more readable, and worry about finding out which is the faster option when you identify a performance problem.

---

Original answer follows:

The second option is more expensive. It sorts everything in ascending order and then reverses the array, two distinct processes, while the first option produces the array in descending order immediately.

That said, the second option is the one I'd prefer. Generally, prefer producing readable, maintainable code over prematurely optimizing for performance.

Obviously you have to ask yourself: "Does this code run many times per second?" or "Does this code run once in the lifetime of the app?" and your priorities will change accordingly, but generally, maintainability trumps performance.

Use the second option until you can prove that it's a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Kind of. The fact is that the `reverse!` is `O(n)`, so negligible compared to the `sort!`, so "more expensive" isn't quite accurate, especially that the need to call a block is very expensive, making the first option much less performant in the end.

Comment: Given @Broi's experiment, I'd change the last line to simply "Use the second option."

Comment: @AShelly It's still hardly proven to be a performance bottleneck. Just because it runs slower in synthetic benchmarks on 10^7 records doesn't mean it's *proven* to be a performance *bottleneck* in a real application. If this is executing once in the lifetime of the app, on inputs of twenty records, there will be no measurable difference in performance.

Answer (score 6):

I was pretty surprised but it seems that the second option is faster, and not just by small %.

```
require 'benchmark'
array = (1..10**7).to_a.shuffle
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { array.sort { |firstBook, secondBook| secondBook <=> firstBook }}
  x.report { array.sort.reverse }
end
```

Results:

```
     user     system      total        real
  21.090000   0.030000  21.120000 ( 21.135562)
   2.060000   0.020000   2.080000 (  2.098318)
```

Comment: My guess is that sort of ints is done completely with internal c functions, while the one with the block needs to keep calling out to the ruby interpreter.

Comment: I was expecting this as `sort_by` requires block calls whereas `sort` directly invokes the C method and reverse is inexpensive operation.

Comment: @meager - It is not, I've changed `sort!` into `sort`, also I've checked `array.first` after all test run - it is a random number, neither `1` nor `10**7`.

Comment: Interestingly, in ruby 1.9.3 the first one is only ~7x slower, where in 1.8 its ~110x.

Comment: @BroiSatse Ah, true. Interestingly, it seems like `.sort.reverse` is *always* faster than calling `.sort { |a,b| b <=> a }`, even for complex types. I suppose `.sort` with no arguments is optimized to iterate over the array and invoke `<=>` natively, while `.sort` with a block must do the invocation of `<=>` in Ruby.