# How to sort! arrays in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to sort my_array and then reverse the order.

Which markup is correct?

```
my_array.sort.reverse!
```

or

```
my_array.sort!.reverse
```

Or does it make any difference?

Thanks

Comment: I think both are wrong xD I would write it (before testing) as my_array.sort!.reverse! That's because if you don't use ! on at least one of them, it will return a copy instead of changing the original IMO. Like I said, I didn't test it. You should, just to make sure :D

Comment: @SlySherZ - Both of them are in fact correct as OP didn't specify what he/she wants to achieve.

Comment: Why sort and then reverse? Why not `my_array.sort { |x,y| y <=> x }`

Comment: I just tested it out, and it works the way I thought it would. I assumed he wanted to change the array he had, otherwise he shouldn't be using ! in the first place :D Summarizing, use double ! to completely change your array or don't use bangs at all to keep it as is

Comment: @caeth - THere was a question regarding this some time ago. `array.sort.reverse` is much faster.

Comment: @BroiSatse ok, cool :)

Comment: @caeth -I found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117907/is-there-a-benefit-to-using-rather-than-just-sorting-and-reversing/21118265#21118265 - quite interesting discussion there. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to decompose the chain :

First, let's understand the difference between the `sort` and the `sort!` method.
If I write

```
array = [7,2,4]
array.sort!
array # => [2,4,7]
```

If you write

```
array = [7,2,4]
foo = array.sort
array # => [7,2,4]
foo # => [2,4,7]
```

The `sort` method sort the array and returns the result as the output of the function, whereas the `sort!` one directly modifies the existing array.

So if you write :

```
my_array.sort.reverse!
```

It is like writing :

```
(my_array.sort). # => Here we create a new array who is calculated by sorting the existing one
reverse! # => Then we reverse this new array, who is not referenced by a variable.
```

If you write :

```
(my_array.sort!). #=> Here you sort my_array and reinject the result into my_array !
reverse  # Then reverse it and inject the result into a NEW array
```

So in both cases, you will not obtain what you want ! What you want to do is either :

```
my_array.sort!.reverse!
```

or :

```
new_array = my_array.sort.reverse
```

Comment: Your explanation really made sense to me and was easy to understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You'll get the same output, but one will modify the initial array. See this:

```
2.1.1 :001 > my_array = ["a","d","b","c"]
 => ["a", "d", "b", "c"]
```

Just declaring an array with a, b, c, and d in completely wrong orders.

```
2.1.1 :002 > my_array.sort.reverse!
 => ["d", "c", "b", "a"]
```

Running your first command on it returns a reverse-sorted array

```
2.1.1 :003 > my_array
 => ["a", "d", "b", "c"]
```

... but doesn't modify the original array itself.

```
2.1.1 :004 > my_array.sort!.reverse
 => ["d", "c", "b", "a"]
```

Running the second command returns the same result, the array sorted backwards

```
2.1.1 :005 > my_array
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

But the array itself has been modified, but *only* by the `sort!` call. A `!` after a method call 'saves' the changes to the object it's called on and returns the result. So in the second one:

- You sort the array, *saving the changes* to it and returning the sorted array, then
- Run `reverse` on the sorted array, which doesn't save to anything and only returns the result.

Answer (score 0):

`my_array.sort!.reverse` will modify the receiver so `my_array` will be sorted after this call e.g.

```
my_array = [1,4,3,5,2]
my_array.sort!.reverse
#=> [5,4,3,2,1]
my_array 
#=> [1,2,3,4,5]
```

the second form my_array.sort.reverse! will not modify `my_array` because `sort` will `dup` the array first then `reverse!` will modify this duped copy which is not being stored. This would have the same impact as `my_array.sort.reverse` without the `!`

```
my_array = [1,4,3,5,2]
my_array.sort.reverse!
#=> [5,4,3,2,1]
my_array 
#=> [1,4,3,5,2]
```

Thirdly, something like `my_array.sort!.reverse!` will modify the receiver twice meaning `my_array.sort!` will sort the array in place and then `.reverse!` will reverse the array in place. so `my_array` will now be sorted and reversed.

```
my_array = [1,4,3,5,2]
my_array.sort!.reverse!
#=> [5,4,3,2,1]
my_array 
#=> [5,4,3,2,1]
```

Although in this case I do not think you will need either bang `!` method as the second form has no impact. bang `!` in ruby means "dangerous", may alter the data or have other unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

```
 my_array.sort!.reverse!
```

is the **correct** answer, since you want to change the array you already have.

```
 my_array.sort.reverse!
```

creates a sorted copy and reverses it (the original doesn't change).

```
 my_array.sort!.reverse
```

sorts the original and creates a reversed copy (the original isn't reversed).